# Rails Active Record - How to do validation which calls method rather than throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Active Record validations throw an error when they fail. What I have in a model is

```
validate_format_of :field_which_cannot_have_spaces, :with => /^[^\s]+$/, :message => "Some error message"
```

What I want instead, is for a string replacement to substitute spaces for underscores (snake_case).

The advantages of using validation for me, are that it runs every time the field is changed unless [`save(validate: false)`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations), and that I don't need to repeat the replacement in the create and update controller methods.

Front end javascript solutions won't help if the user hacks the form... a rails solution is needed!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) rather than a validation. This can run each time your object is modified.

So, to remove spaces from your field before the object is saved you can do:

```
before_save :remove_spaces_from_x

def remove_spaces_from_x
  self.field_which_cannot_have_spaces.gsub!("\s","_")
end
```

Note also that validation do not always raise an error when they fail. If you use `save!` or `create!` then an error is raised but if you use the equivalent `save` or `create` then no error is raised, `false` is returned and the object's `errors` are populated with details of the validation failure.

Answer (score 0):

Co-worker just told me to do the following in the model:

```
def field_which_cannot_have_spaces=(input_from_form)
  super(input_from_form.gsub("\s","_"))
end
```

This will change the value as it is set.

"Validations are for informing the client there is a problem, and shouldn't be doing something other than throwing an error."

Hope this helps someone else...